# Call hierarchy and/or data flow tool for Scala

Tags: java, maven-2, ide, scala, call

Is there an IDE/Tool/script/something that can show call hierarchy and/or data flow in Scala+Java programs (preferably from source code).
Or (as a backup plan) is there a tool that can show it using Java bytecode? (And preferably give the option to go to source code, if provided by user).
All that, preferably integrated into an IDE and/or Maven :-) 
The requirement to support Scala is crucial in this question. I Already know of and use such tools for Java, in 3 IDEs. They do not work very well (actually: at all) when Scala is involved. 
TIA

Comment: This would be a boon to IntelliJ particularly where mixed Java/Scala stacks are concerned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poor man's call hierarchy: Comment the method out and see where your red squigglies show up. [/me ducks]

Comment: Indeed, that sometimes comes in handy. But i would rather call it "show usages"

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

[SBT](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/) can do that. You'll have to check it out to get more information, because I haven't done it.

**EDIT**

Sorry, I confused things. SBT can generate component dependencies, not call hierarchy.